# Discord.js command check empty space only once

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

when someone inputs a command `!add James Bond;Michael B Jordan` the argument takes it as "James"arg[0], "Bond;Michale"args[1], "B"args[2], "Jordan"args[3]. Any way i can make it so that it only counts the empty space after the "!add" and then splits using ";" ?. Final answer would be "James Bond"args[0], "Michael B Jordan"args[1].

```
client.on('message',async(message)=>{

if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix2)||message.author.bot)return;
const args2=message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const command= args2.shift().toLowerCase();
```

This is what i tried but it doesnt seem to work

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix2)||message.author.bot)return;
const args2=message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ {1}[;]+/);
const command= args2.shift().toLowerCase();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know `!add`   will always takeup 5 characters of the string, we can crop out those 5 using [String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).
This will then return `'James Bond;Michael B Jordan'`,   which we can ofcourse split by `;` to return each name in it's own array element.

```
client.on('message', async(message) => {
   // message.content = '!add James Bond;Michael B Jordan'
   const rawContent = message.content.slice(5);
   const celebrityArguments = rawContent.split(';');

   console.log(celebrityArguments);
   // ["James Bond", "Michael B Jordan"]
})
```